# can't get a service to start - launching and killing with checkbox (code in post)

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediarecorder

i'm a java noob, so sorry for the noob question...

i have a checkbox that is supposed to fire off a service when checked - kill it when unchecked.
the "attempting..." toast pops up as expected, but the services does not seem to be starting and does not present toast..

here are my mainifest entries, main activity code (abbridged), and the service code:

```
// manifest entries

<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" >
 <activity android:name=".MainMenu" android:label="@string/app_name" >
  <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
 </activity>
 <service android:name=".PPS" android:process=":remote" android:label="@string/service_name" />
</application>

// MainMenu.java

final CheckBox checkBoxStartService = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxEnable);
checkBoxStartService.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
 {
  if (checkBoxStartService.isChecked() == true) 
  {       // make toast
  Toast toaster = Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "attempting to start service...", 500);
  toaster.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, -200);
  toaster.show();
  Intent startPPS = new Intent();
  startPPS.putExtra("com.domain.notlaunchingservice.PPS", false);
  startService(startPPS); 
  }
  if (checkBoxStartService.isChecked() == false)
  {
  Intent closePPS = new Intent();
  closePPS.putExtra("com.domain.notlaunchingservice.PPS", true);
  stopService(closePPS);
  }
 }
};

// PPS.java

package com.domain.notlaunchingservice;
import android.app.Service;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.Toast;
public abstract class PPS extends Service
{
 @Override
 public void onCreate()
 {
  Toast toasty = Toast.makeText(PPS.this, "service created!", 500);
  toasty.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 200);
  toasty.show();
 };
 public void onDestroy()
 {
  Toast toasted = Toast.makeText(PPS.this, "service destroyed!", 500);
  toasted.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, -200);
  toasted.show();
 }; 
};
```

i have also tried to call the service using:

```
startService(new Intent(MainMenu.this, PPS.class));
```

this returns an error on the emulator saying the app quit unexpectedly and i click force close, but the main activity doesn't close, so i'm assuming it's the service that i am force closing.
below is the DDMS output:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.domain.notlaunchingservice.PPS
```

i don't care how i get the service started, as long as it can load a SQL base and continue recording audio to a file after the main activity loses focus or is closed.

this will be a free app on the market when finished, so your help will be appreciated by many when the project is ready for prime time.

thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the intent you use to start and stop the service only specifies an extra.

```
Intent startPPS = new Intent();
```

should be

```
Intent startPPS = new Intent(this, PPS.class);
```

But there are other problems as well (I don't think your example compiles), I would recommend you to look at the example at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#ExtendingIntentService

Edit: (example code below)

```
public class StartedService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // I guess that you don't want to bind to the service
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service is running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Return sticky if you want it to be restarted in a low memory
        // situation
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service is going down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


public class ClientActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button startButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                startService(new Intent(ClientActivity.this, StartedService.class));
            }

        });

        Button stopButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                stopService(new Intent(ClientActivity.this, StartedService.class));
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it compiles, but the service doesn't start.

Comment: using the second method, the service seems to start, then immediately crash.

Comment: whoa dude....that example is way over my head. i'm just starting out in android programming, so i'm trying to keep it basic by building on what i've got so far.

Comment: keep in mind that the MainMenu code is just a snippet. that may be what you meant by "(i don't think your example compiles)".

Comment: Extending the IntentService class is the easiest and simplest way to implement a started service. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: the ONLY thing i need the main activity to do is start and stop the service. once it starts, it needs no intervention other than a way to kill it.

Comment: using an intent to start the service as suggested above returns the same error as starting it without the intent. is there something wrong with the code for the PPS class?